# Regenerate keystore.jks file from p7b or crt file

Tags: tomcat, certificate, keystore, keytool, p7b

I'm in a rather unlucky situation, as the keystore generated when creating a CSR file with the keytool is "lost".

I have received the p7b file and I also have the crt file available, which both are produced from the CSR.

Is it somehow possible to create a keystore from these files with the keytool ?

I tried to create a new keystore, but this doesn't work as I get a "Certificate reply does not contain public key for ...." when importing the p7b certificate file.

Would really much appreciate help on this.

---

Found a solution, which is to generate a new keystore and csr file, and re-key the certificate with the newly generated csr file.

Comment: I by the way also have the CSR file, all I'm missing is the keystore...

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it. Others may profit from it.

Comment: Solution was already mentioned, but now I have done it the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, which is to generate a new keystore and csr file using the keytool. Afterwards the already purchased certificate is re-keyed at the certificate provider using the new generated CSR. 
Re-keying was an online process, so no problems doing this.